# How to use Cheerio in NodeJS to scrape img srcs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

This is the code

```
const getHappyMovies = async () => {
  try {
    const movieData = [];
    let title;
    let description;
    let imageUrl;
    const response = await axios.get(happyUrl); //https://www.imdb.com/list/ls008985796/
    const $ = load(response.data);
    const movies = $(".lister-item");
    movies.each(function () {
      title = $(this).find("h3 a").text();
      description = $(this).find("p").eq(1).text();
      imageUrl = $(this).find("a img").attr("src");
      movieData.push({ title, description, imageUrl });
    });
    console.log(movieData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Here's the output I'm receiving:
[image]

And this is the website I'm scraping from

[image]

Now I need to get the src of that image, but it's returning something else, as shown in the output image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The golden rule of Cheerio is "it doesn't run JS". As a result, devtools is often inaccurate since it shows the state of the page after JS runs.

Instead, either look at `view-source:`, disable JS or look at the HTML response printed from your terminal to get a more accurate sense of what's actually on the page (or not).

Looking at the source:

```html
<img alt="Tokyo Story"
class="loadlate"
loadlate="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYWQ4ZTRiODktNjAzZC00Nzg1LTk1YWQtNDFmNDI0NmZiNGIwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_UY209_CR2,0,140,209_AL_.jpg"
data-tconst="tt0046438"
height="209"
src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/sash/4FyxwxECzL-U1J8.png"
width="140" />
```

You can see `src=` is a placeholder image but `loadlate` is the actual URL. When the image is scrolled into view, JS kicks in and lazily loads the `loadlate` URL into the `src` attribute, leading to your observed devtools state.

The solution is to use `.attr("loadlate")`:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

const getHappyMovies = () =>
  axios.get(url).then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    return [...$(".lister-item")].map(e => ({
      title: $(e).find(".lister-item-header a").text(),
      description: $(e).find(".lister-item-content p").eq(1).text().trim(),
      imageUrl: $(e).find(".lister-item-image img").attr("loadlate"),
    }));
  });

getHappyMovies().then(movies => console.log(movies));
```

Note that I'm using class selectors which are more specific than plain tags.

Comment: Yes, and with this detailed answer, I learned how to disable javascript, and checking the returned html from cheerio.
It's better to check the html that was returned.